# Using eclipse for project in multiple different environments

Tags: eclipse

If I want to use eclipse for projects in different environments,
what is the recommended way to work? 
Install multiple instances of eclipse each configured differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No ... the typical why is you have for each of your projects a separate workspace. 
All configurations are collected in this workspace. The only exceptions is if you need different plugin for the different environments, but usually this is not the case.

There is a nice tool from a google developer

http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic

which help you to sync some general settings between different workspace.

Comment: can you please elaborate on the plugin issue ?
I need to develop in php & in java (for a web site & for android).

Comment: @epeleg well there may be projects which require different plugin's which work not together in on installation ... but i think this isn't very often the case. And in worst case you still can use two installation of eclipse ... php & java should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Basically yes - things that make it easier for me are the Eclipse [Workspace Mechanic](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic/) (I have a folder with config files on my Dropbox, and reference that from the Workspace Mechanic preferences in the different Eclipse instances, so I automatically have them configured) and [Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/) (with which the data is usually stored centrally anyway and the settings can be exported and imported in a different Eclipse instance - I keep such an export on my Dropbox again).